# How to draw a image in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, canvas, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to draw a image using canvas but I got this error from browser:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'drawImage' of undefined  at Image.img.onload (test.js:23)
```

I put some messages on console.log() to help and the result is this:

```
args: 0 50 100
canvas: <canvas width=​"320" height=​"320">​
this.img.src: http://localhost:3000/img/img1.jpg
this.ctx: undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'drawImage' of undefined  at Image.img.onload (test.js:23)
```

The problem is **undefined "this.ctx"** but I don't know why.
Someone can help me please ?  Below my code:

My .js:

```js
var myVm = new Vue({
  el: '#draw-image-test',
  data: {
    items: [
      { id: 1, src: 'img/img1.jpg' },
      { id: 2, src: 'img/img2.jpg' },
      { id: 3, src: 'img/img3.jpg' }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    drawItem(index, x, y) {
      console.log('args:', index, x, y);
      this.canvas = this.$refs.canRef;
      console.log("canvas:", this.canvas);
      this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
      this.img = new Image();
      this.img.src = this.items[index].src;
      console.log('this.img.src:', this.img.src);
      this.img.onload = function () {
        console.log('this.ctx:', this.ctx);
        this.ctx.drawImage(this.img, x, y);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

My HTML:

```html
<div id="draw-image-test">
    <canvas width="320" height="320" ref="canRef"></canvas>
    <button v-on:click="drawItem(0, 50, 100)">Draw item 0</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign `this` component instance to a global variable `vm` and use it inside the callback as follows  :

```
  console.log('this.img.src:', this.img.src);
  let vm=this;
      this.img.onload = function () {
        console.log('vm.ctx:', vm.ctx);
        vm.ctx.drawImage(vm.img, x, y);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to share the [answer from Jayesh](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-draw-a-image-in-vue-js/92258/2?u=jantunes) that works perfectly:

---

The problem is with on load function, this cannot be accessed with the on load function. Either you can use arrow function or define a local variable for this and access that within on load function.

```
this.img.onload = () => {
   console.log('this.ctx:', this.ctx);
   this.ctx.drawImage(this.img, x, y);
}
```

or

```
drawItem(index, x, y) {
const self = this;
.
.
.
this.img.onload = function () {
   console.log('ctx:', self.ctx);
   self.ctx.drawImage(self.img, x, y);
}
```